# Resize uiscrollview after scaling so as to enable paging

Tags: ios, iphone

I am having a scrollview containing 2 image views in one page only.I am scaling scrollview so as to cover full screen on tapping.Now i want after scaling, paging should be enabled.But then it skip every alternate image view. Any help would be appreciated.`

```
kNumViews = 10;
vScrollObjectHeight = 230;  // half screen
vScrollObjectWidth = 160;   // half screen
{
 for (i = 1; i <= kNumViews; i++)
 {


    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageV%d.jpg", i];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     [imageView sizeToFit];
     imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
     imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;

     CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
     rect.size.height = vScrollObjHeight;
     rect.size.width = vScrollObjWidth;
     imageView.frame = rect;
     imageView.tag = i;

     imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [scrollView2 addSubview:imageView];

}
[self layoutScrollViews];
self.swipeRecognizerUp = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleMove:)];
[self.swipeRecognizerUp setDelegate:self];
[scrollView2 addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeRecognizerUp];

self.swipeRecognizerDown = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleDown:)];
[self.swipeRecognizerDown setDelegate:self];
[scrollView2 addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeRecognizerDown];
self.swipeRecognizerDown.enabled = NO;

}


-(void)scaleMove:(id)sender {

    [[[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[sender view]];

    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    if(abs(velocity.y) - abs(velocity.x) > 500 && velocity.y < 0){
    [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    //[sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 230);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^(){
                         CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
                         CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-230);
                         [sender view].transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
                         //NSLog(@"%f %f",[sender view].frame.size.width,[sender view].frame.size.height);
                         scrollView2.pagingEnabled = YES;




                     }
                     completion:nil];
    self.swipeRecognizerDown.enabled = YES;
    self.swipeRecognizerUp.enabled = NO;
    }

}

}
`
```

Comment: @Retro i have shared the code.Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer of it...I have set the width of scrollview half and then subclasses the scrollview so as to override pointInside and then normally scaled scrollview.found answer of it...I have set the width of scrollview half and then subclasses the scrollview so as to override pointInside and then normally scaled scrollview.